# Handle CTRL-C in Python cmd module

Tags: python, sigint, python-cmd

I wrote a Python 3.5 application using the cmd module. The last thing I would like to implement is proper handling of the CTRL-C (sigint) signal. I would like it to behave more or less the way Bash does it:

- print ^C at the point the cursor is
- clear the buffer so that the input text is deleted
- skip to the next line, print the prompt, and wait for input

Basically:

```
/test $ bla bla bla|
# user types CTRL-C
/test $ bla bla bla^C
/test $
```

Here is simplified code as a runnable sample:

```
import cmd
import signal


class TestShell(cmd.Cmd):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.prompt = '$ '

        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler=self._ctrl_c_handler)
        self._interrupted = False

    def _ctrl_c_handler(self, signal, frame):
        print('^C')
        self._interrupted = True

    def precmd(self, line):
        if self._interrupted:
            self._interrupted = False
            return ''

        if line == 'EOF':
            return 'exit'

        return line

    def emptyline(self):
        pass

    def do_exit(self, line):
        return True


TestShell().cmdloop()
```

This almost works. When I press CTRL-C, ^C is printed at the cursor, but I still have to press enter. Then, the `precmd` method notices its `self._interrupted` flag set by the handler, and returns an empty line. This is as far as I could take it, but I would like to somehow not have to press that enter.

I guess I somehow need to force the `input()` to return, does anybody have ideas?

Comment: It would help to have a small runnable sample.  Without running your code how you're currently going about it, would writing a `'\n'` or blank to `stdout` suffice?  That is once signal handler is tripped tack a newline on the end of `'^C'`

Comment: @tijko Edited the post by replacing the snippet with a runnable sample. I tried writing a newline to stdout (it is actually done by default by the print method), but it does't work, and why would it? It would require for stdin be fed from stdout, which is not the case, it's not piped.

Comment: Yeah, you're right I wasn't thinking in terms of command line stdin prompt.  @DanGetz has an answer that will suit your needs I believe.  Its cleaner too, no need to set signal handler or set flags.  After your comment I started to think along the lines of redirecting stdin aswell, you can adjust to however you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found some hacky ways to achieve the behavior you want with Ctrl-C.

## Set `use_rawinput=False` and replace `stdin`

This one sticks (more or less…) to the public interface of `cmd.Cmd`. Unfortunately, it disables readline support.

You can set `use_rawinput` to false and pass a different file-like object to replace `stdin` in `Cmd.__init__()`. In practice, only `readline()` is called on this object. So you can create a wrapper for `stdin` that catches the `KeyboardInterrupt` and executes the behavior you want instead:

```
class _Wrapper:

    def __init__(self, fd):
        self.fd = fd

    def readline(self, *args):
        try:
            return self.fd.readline(*args)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print()
            return '\n'


class TestShell(cmd.Cmd):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(stdin=_Wrapper(sys.stdin))
        self.use_rawinput = False
        self.prompt = '$ '

    def precmd(self, line):
        if line == 'EOF':
            return 'exit'
        return line

    def emptyline(self):
        pass

    def do_exit(self, line):
        return True


TestShell().cmdloop()
```

When I run this on my terminal, Ctrl-C shows `^C` and switches to a new line.

## Monkey-patch `input()`

If you want the results of `input()`, except you want different behavior for Ctrl-C, one way to do that would be to use a different function instead of `input()`:

```
def my_input(*args):   # input() takes either no args or one non-keyword arg
    try:
        return input(*args)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('^C')   # on my system, input() doesn't show the ^C
        return '\n'
```

However, if you just blindly set `input = my_input`, you get infinite recursion because `my_input()` will call `input()`, which is now itself. But that's fixable, and you can patch the `__builtins__` dictionary in the `cmd` module to use your modified `input()` method during `Cmd.cmdloop()`:

```
def input_swallowing_interrupt(_input):
    def _input_swallowing_interrupt(*args):
        try:
            return _input(*args)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('^C')
            return '\n'
    return _input_swallowing_interrupt


class TestShell(cmd.Cmd):

    def cmdloop(self, *args, **kwargs):
        old_input_fn = cmd.__builtins__['input']
        cmd.__builtins__['input'] = input_swallowing_interrupt(old_input_fn)
        try:
            super().cmdloop(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            cmd.__builtins__['input'] = old_input_fn

    # ...
```

Note that this changes `input()` for **all `Cmd` objects**, not just `TestShell` objects. If this isn't acceptable to you, you could…

## Copy the `Cmd.cmdloop()` source and modify it

Since you're subclassing it, you can make `cmdloop()` do anything you want. "Anything you want" could include copying parts of `Cmd.cmdloop()` and rewriting others. Either replace the call to `input()` with a call to another function, or catch and handle `KeyboardInterrupt` right there in your rewritten `cmdloop()`.

If you're afraid of the underlying implementation changing with new versions of Python, you could copy the whole `cmd` module into a new module, and change what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Unfortunately, I'm using readline and it is pretty important.

Comment: @wujek yeah, I expected as much. Well, there's a slightly hackier way to handle that I guess, I'll add it.

Comment: I took option 3, just copied the cmdloop() code and changed. I think it is the least hacky solution... Thanks!